# mysql problems after Mac OS X software update

Tags: mysql, php, mac-osx

After running Mac OS X updates this morning when I run PHP projects on my local machine, when they were fine last night are now giving me errors:

```
mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 540]
```

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Jonesy

Answer (score 3):

From apple support forum :
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=12176949

---

I had the same problem and fixed it by editing my php.ini file:

1. In Terminal type
   sudo nano /etc/php.ini
   (Terminal will ask you for your password)
2. Change:
   mysql.default_socket =
   to:
   mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
3. Press Ctrl-O, then Enter to save
4. Still in Terminal, type sudo apachectl graceful
5. That's it!

---

Comment: thanks for the link. It hasn't fixed it though, is it anything to do with me having a php.default.ini instead?

Comment: I don't think PHP will read `php.default.ini`. [This FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.phpini) explains where to find `php.ini` - you might just rename `php.default.ini` to `php.ini`.

Comment: Also consider changing `mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock` for MySQLi and `pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock` for PDO

Answer (score 1):

It appears that MySQL is no longer running. How did you install MySQL? Does it report any error when you try to start/restart it?

Comment: it's running but when I try to restart it i get an error: Stopping server...
 ERROR! MySQL manager or server PID file could not be found!
Failed to stop server, trying shutdown...
Stopped server.

Comment: I'm using MySQL Administrator for MacOSX btw

Comment: Has your /etc/my.cnf file changed? Maybe you're connecting via TCP or something now? When in the mysql client, type \s to see where the socket is now (or if you're using TCP, etc)

Answer (score 0):

you can start the mysqld deamon pointing to any socket file that you want. You just have to say to the client as well which file you want to use.

In your case i would:

- check if the /var/mysql directory exists
- check if your user has permission to write file on this directory

you can try to start your deamon using a socket file like:

```
mysqld_safe --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

and then with your mysqlclient you can do something like

```
mysql -u user -p --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

it will work